# Disable time selection in jquery DateTimePicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

Using `dateTimePicker`. I'm trying range between date. When I select the day it's working, but the hours section is not working. The picture makes it more understandable:

[image: My image here]

My code:

```js
$("#start_datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
  lang: "tr", 
  format:"d/m/Y H:i", 
  onShow:function(ct){
    this.setOptions({
      maxDate: jQuery("#end_datetimepicker").val() ? jQuery("#end_datetimepicker").val() : false, 
      formatDate:"d/m/Y H:i"
    })
  }
});

$("#end_datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
  lang: "tr", 
  format:"d/m/Y H:i", 
  onShow:function(ct){
    this.setOptions({
      minDate: jQuery("#start_datetimepicker").val() ? jQuery("#start_datetimepicker").val() : false,
      formatDate:"d/m/Y H:i"
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: which datetimepicker you are using ?

Comment: I using http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker here

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `timepicker:false` option

Try this

```
$("#start_datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
  lang: "tr", 
  format:"d/m/Y",
  timepicker:false, 
  onShow:function(ct){
    this.setOptions({
      maxDate: jQuery("#end_datetimepicker").val() ? jQuery("#end_datetimepicker").val() : false, 
      formatDate:"d/m/Y"
    })
  }
});

$("#end_datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
  lang: "tr", 
  format:"d/m/Y",
  timepicker:false, 
  onShow:function(ct){
    this.setOptions({
      minDate: jQuery("#start_datetimepicker").val() ? jQuery("#start_datetimepicker").val() : false,
      formatDate:"d/m/Y"
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue, don't use timepicker:false. It will totally disable the timepicker. Instead use the `defaultTime: '18:00'`, this 18:00 can be your start time. Pls read the doc [here](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#defaultTime). If input value is empty, timepicker set time use defaultTime. This may help someone.